# Test website on iphone from linux

Tags: ios, iphone, debugging

I have a website and client says it is not working on his iPhone6 browser. Tested layout with chrome dev tools, but most likely problem is not in layout, but some js error occurred.

I have a linux desktop and android device. Is there any way to install/emulate iOS anywhere?

**UPD**

Ok, this is impossible without device or laptop with iOS. I'll try to install it on vmware or virtualbox.

**UPD2**

One more way to see the error - setup sentry to log js errors and ask client to test it again

Comment: Unfortunately the only truly reliable way to test an iPhone issue is to test on an iPhone. You can use safari on a Mac to remotely debug Safari on the iPhone. The iOS simulator safari may not accurately reflect the real device, but is probably a reasonable starting point. As Vasili says, you need a Mac with Xcode to run the simulator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iOS could be emulated only through Xcode on Mac OS.
Even though, you always can emulate Mac OS ;)

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. This website saved me: https://appetize.io/app/standalone_2p3b4d0weqbr42d31n6cfqby74?device=iphone8&scale=75&orientation=portrait&osVersion=13.7

The emulator that you see on the front page only works for 60 seconds but if you sign up (and don't choose a paid subscription) you can still test it for free in an emulator that can run for longer time. There you can also choose phone type, iOS version etc...